# Why does the training time increase when I use "make_saveable_from_iterator" to add the iterator state to Saver?

Tags: tensorflow, iterator, deep-learning

I use tf.data.TextLineDataset to generate my input data, and I create an iterator for the dataset.

```
def dataInput(filenames,epoch_num,batch_size):
    default_column_value = [[0] for i in range(2)]
    default_column_value.extend([[0.0] for i in range(1500)])
    default_column_value.extend([[0.0] for i in range(2100)])
    default_column_value.extend([[0] for i in range(2)])

    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(tf.constant(filenames))
    dataset = dataset.map(lambda line: tf.decode_csv(
                line, record_defaults=default_column_value)).repeat(epoch_num).shuffle(buffer_size=2000).batch(batch_size)
    return dataset

train_data=dataInput(FLAGS.train_data_list,epoch_num=FLAGS.epoch,batch_size=batch_sz)
train_data_iterator = train_data.make_initializable_iterator()
```

and I use iterator.get_next() in a function to get the data used for the model.

```
def get_next(iterator):
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    atom_length=next_element[0]
    relation_length=next_element[1]
    atom = tf.stack(next_element[2:1502],axis=1)
    relation = tf.stack(next_element[1502:2202],axis=1)
    protein_sequence = tf.stack(next_element[2202:3602],axis=1)
    protein_length= next_element[-2]
    labels = tf.one_hot(next_element[-1],depth=2,on_value=1,off_value=0)
    return atom_length,relation_length,protein_length,atom,relation,protein_sequence,labels
```

**I need to make my model have the ability to continue training from the saving checkpoint, so the state of the training dataset iterator also needs to be saved.**

So I refer the content of [Saving iterator state](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets) part from Tensorflow guide. And I use the following code to add the state of the iterator to tf.train.Saver.

```
saveable = tf.data.experimental.make_saveable_from_iterator(train_data_iterator)
tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS, saveable)

saver_vars=tf.global_variables()+tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.SAVEABLE_OBJECTS)
saver = tf.train.Saver(saver_vars)
```

and then I initialize variables and training.

```
global_variables_initialize=tf.global_variables_initializer()
local_variables_initialize=tf.local_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(global_variables_initialize)

    latest_ckpt_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir,hparam)
    latest_ckpt=tf.train.latest_checkpoint(latest_ckpt_path)
    if latest_ckpt:
        print("Have existing model, restoring...")
        saver.restore(sess, latest_ckpt)
        print("Continue training...")
    else:
        print("First training, initialize train data iterator...")
        sess.run(train_data_iterator.initializer)
        print("Start training...")

    writer.add_graph(sess.graph)

    try:
        epoch_start_time=time.time()
        onestep_time="0.0"
        while(True):
            one_step_time=time.time()
            atom_length,relation_length,protein_length,atom,relation,protein_sequence,labels=sess.run([train_atom_length,train_relation_length,train_protein_length,train_atom,train_relation,train_protein_sequence,train_labels])
            step=int(sess.run(global_steps))
            epoch=1+step//(FLAGS.train_sample_num//batch_sz+1)
            # print training accuracy every 5 steps
            if step%5==0:
                acc=sess.run(accuracy,feed_dict={seqlen_atom:atom_length/FLAGS.atom_diminput, seqlen_relation:relation_length/FLAGS.relation_diminput, seqlen_protein:protein_length/FLAGS.protein_diminput, x_atom:atom, x_relation:relation, x_protein:protein_sequence, y_label:labels, is_training:False})
                print("epoch {:d}, Step {:d}, Training Accuracy={:.5f}, UsedTime: {}".format(epoch,step,acc,onestep_time))

            # run on validation set every 50 steps and get metrics
            if step%50==0:
                sess.run(local_variables_initialize)
                val_labels=sess.run(val_labels_tensor)
                val_acc,tp_score,tn_score,fp_score,fn_score,precision_score,recall_score,F1_score,auc_score,rs=sess.run([accuracy,tp_update,tn_update,fp_update,fn_update,precision_update,recall_update,F1_update,auc_update,merged],feed_dict={seqlen_atom:val_atom_length/FLAGS.atom_diminput, seqlen_relation:val_relation_length/FLAGS.relation_diminput, seqlen_protein:val_protein_length/FLAGS.protein_diminput, x_atom:val_atom, x_relation:val_relation, x_protein:val_protein_sequence, y_label:val_labels, is_training:False})
                writer.add_summary(rs, step)
                writer.flush()
#                    print("epoch {:d}, Step {:d}, Validation Accuracy={:.5f}, AUC={:.4f}".format(epoch,step,val_acc,auc_score))
                print("Val tp={:.4f}, tn={:.4f}, fp={:.4f}, fn={:.4f}".format(tp_score,tn_score,fp_score,fn_score))
                print("Val Acc={:.4f}, pr={:.4f}, re={:.4f}, F1={:.4f}, AUC={:.4f}".format(val_acc,precision_score,recall_score,F1_score,auc_score))

            # Save model
            if step%200 == 0:
                savetime_before=time.time()
                checkpoint_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir,hparam,"epoch"+str(epoch)+"_step"+ str(step)+".ckpt")
                saver.save(sess,checkpoint_file,global_step=step)
                used_savetime=str(time.time()-savetime_before)
                print("saving cost time: {}".format(used_savetime))

            sess.run([train_op, update_ops],feed_dict={seqlen_atom:atom_length/FLAGS.atom_diminput, seqlen_relation:relation_length/FLAGS.relation_diminput, seqlen_protein:protein_length/FLAGS.protein_diminput, x_atom:atom, x_relation:relation, x_protein:protein_sequence, y_label:labels, is_training:True})
            onestep_time=str(time.time()-one_step_time)

    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError:
        print("End of epochs.")
        checkpoint_file = os.path.join(FLAGS.model_dir,hparam,"epoch"+str(epoch)+"_step"+ str(step)+".ckpt")
        saver.save(sess,checkpoint_file,global_step=step)
    finally:
        print('epochs time:',time.time()-epoch_start_time)
```

**My problem is the training time and the saving time increased every time when the saving process run.**  *Specifically, In my code above, I save model when "step%200 == 0". And the training time and saving time increase every 200 steps.*

I check the while loop but there is no tf opreation causing time increase.

The result in the console is as follows:

```
First training, initialize train data iterator...
Start training...
epoch 1, Step 0, Training Accuracy=0.46094, UsedTime: 0.0
Val tp=0.0000, tn=9983.0000, fp=0.0000, fn=10017.0000
Val Acc=0.4992, pr=0.0000, re=0.0000, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5000
saving cost time: 26.217885971069336
epoch 1, Step 5, Training Accuracy=0.44531, UsedTime: 2.4823594093322754
epoch 1, Step 10, Training Accuracy=0.40625, UsedTime: 2.512277603149414
epoch 1, Step 15, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.5132768154144287
epoch 1, Step 20, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.484353542327881
epoch 1, Step 25, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.4654033184051514
epoch 1, Step 30, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.6169989109039307
epoch 1, Step 35, Training Accuracy=0.45312, UsedTime: 2.4923512935638428
epoch 1, Step 40, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.491335153579712
epoch 1, Step 45, Training Accuracy=0.46094, UsedTime: 2.333726406097412
epoch 1, Step 50, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.5132761001586914
Val tp=10017.0000, tn=0.0000, fp=9983.0000, fn=0.0000
Val Acc=0.5009, pr=0.5009, re=1.0000, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5000
epoch 1, Step 55, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.6020383834838867
epoch 1, Step 60, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 2.5881006717681885
epoch 1, Step 65, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.6579179763793945
epoch 1, Step 70, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.667863130569458
epoch 1, Step 75, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.358689308166504
epoch 1, Step 80, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.7647855281829834
epoch 1, Step 85, Training Accuracy=0.44531, UsedTime: 2.551201581954956
epoch 1, Step 90, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.607024908065796
epoch 1, Step 95, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.6010422706604004
epoch 1, Step 100, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.589071750640869
Val tp=10017.0000, tn=0.0000, fp=9983.0000, fn=0.0000
Val Acc=0.5009, pr=0.5009, re=1.0000, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5000
epoch 1, Step 105, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.5352160930633545
epoch 1, Step 110, Training Accuracy=0.46094, UsedTime: 2.455430030822754
epoch 1, Step 115, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 2.5880472660064697
epoch 1, Step 120, Training Accuracy=0.44531, UsedTime: 2.53721022605896
epoch 1, Step 125, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.5062942504882812
epoch 1, Step 130, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.5153024196624756
epoch 1, Step 135, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 2.5421977043151855
epoch 1, Step 140, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.594059705734253
epoch 1, Step 145, Training Accuracy=0.44531, UsedTime: 2.6359474658966064
epoch 1, Step 150, Training Accuracy=0.42188, UsedTime: 2.5481505393981934
Val tp=10017.0000, tn=0.0000, fp=9983.0000, fn=0.0000
Val Acc=0.5009, pr=0.5009, re=1.0000, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5000
epoch 1, Step 155, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.5511741638183594
epoch 1, Step 160, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.612011432647705
epoch 1, Step 165, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.6309611797332764
epoch 1, Step 170, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 2.4614148139953613
epoch 1, Step 175, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.619990110397339
epoch 1, Step 180, Training Accuracy=0.44531, UsedTime: 2.5322256088256836
epoch 1, Step 185, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.560122013092041
epoch 1, Step 190, Training Accuracy=0.45312, UsedTime: 2.5132763385772705
epoch 1, Step 195, Training Accuracy=0.46094, UsedTime: 2.568129301071167
epoch 1, Step 200, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.5392067432403564
Val tp=0.0000, tn=9981.0000, fp=2.0000, fn=10017.0000
Val Acc=0.4990, pr=0.0000, re=0.0000, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5000
saving cost time: 33.794609785079956
epoch 1, Step 205, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.737675666809082
epoch 1, Step 210, Training Accuracy=0.44531, UsedTime: 2.7097220420837402
epoch 1, Step 215, Training Accuracy=0.45312, UsedTime: 2.7606141567230225
epoch 1, Step 220, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.6299901008605957
epoch 1, Step 225, Training Accuracy=0.58594, UsedTime: 2.670860528945923
epoch 1, Step 230, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.744657278060913
epoch 1, Step 235, Training Accuracy=0.39844, UsedTime: 2.7875146865844727
epoch 1, Step 240, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.72371244430542
epoch 1, Step 245, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.764603614807129
epoch 1, Step 250, Training Accuracy=0.45312, UsedTime: 2.711744546890259
Val tp=10017.0000, tn=0.0000, fp=9983.0000, fn=0.0000
Val Acc=0.5009, pr=0.5009, re=1.0000, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5000
epoch 1, Step 255, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.717728853225708
epoch 1, Step 260, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.77557373046875
epoch 1, Step 265, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.7167582511901855
epoch 1, Step 270, Training Accuracy=0.60938, UsedTime: 2.7236855030059814
epoch 1, Step 275, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.830427408218384
epoch 1, Step 280, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 2.961078643798828
epoch 1, Step 285, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.6389265060424805
epoch 1, Step 290, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.6978096961975098
epoch 1, Step 295, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.7127413749694824
epoch 1, Step 300, Training Accuracy=0.46094, UsedTime: 2.7406888008117676
Val tp=10017.0000, tn=0.0000, fp=9983.0000, fn=0.0000
Val Acc=0.5009, pr=0.5009, re=1.0000, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5330
epoch 1, Step 305, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.809483051300049
epoch 1, Step 310, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.9161975383758545
epoch 1, Step 315, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.9481117725372314
epoch 1, Step 320, Training Accuracy=0.46094, UsedTime: 2.7336859703063965
epoch 1, Step 325, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.7087252140045166
epoch 1, Step 330, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.80151104927063
epoch 1, Step 335, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 2.7646028995513916
epoch 1, Step 340, Training Accuracy=0.57812, UsedTime: 2.8124756813049316
epoch 1, Step 345, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.807461738586426
epoch 1, Step 350, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.770587921142578
Val tp=1889.0000, tn=8543.0000, fp=1440.0000, fn=8128.0000
Val Acc=0.5216, pr=0.5674, re=0.1886, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5425
epoch 1, Step 355, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.7446835041046143
epoch 1, Step 360, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 2.711717128753662
epoch 1, Step 365, Training Accuracy=0.57812, UsedTime: 2.6808273792266846
epoch 1, Step 370, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.9560906887054443
epoch 1, Step 375, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.762608528137207
epoch 1, Step 380, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.756624937057495
epoch 1, Step 385, Training Accuracy=0.40625, UsedTime: 2.81646466255188
epoch 1, Step 390, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 2.788539171218872
epoch 1, Step 395, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.788538694381714
epoch 1, Step 400, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.7576496601104736
Val tp=6752.0000, tn=3977.0000, fp=6006.0000, fn=3265.0000
Val Acc=0.5365, pr=0.5292, re=0.6741, F1=0.6678, AUC=0.5630
saving cost time: 33.959359645843506
epoch 1, Step 405, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.8166308403015137
epoch 1, Step 410, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.740837574005127
epoch 1, Step 415, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.874941110610962
epoch 1, Step 420, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 2.746166467666626
epoch 1, Step 425, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.800095558166504
epoch 1, Step 430, Training Accuracy=0.63281, UsedTime: 2.8913440704345703
epoch 1, Step 435, Training Accuracy=0.54688, UsedTime: 2.9372661113739014
epoch 1, Step 440, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.7706825733184814
epoch 1, Step 445, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 2.866353988647461
epoch 1, Step 450, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.813272714614868
Val tp=0.0000, tn=9983.0000, fp=0.0000, fn=10017.0000
Val Acc=0.4992, pr=0.0000, re=0.0000, F1=0.6675, AUC=0.5369
epoch 1, Step 455, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 2.7971560955047607
epoch 1, Step 460, Training Accuracy=0.54688, UsedTime: 2.7972328662872314
epoch 1, Step 465, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.746523857116699
epoch 1, Step 470, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 2.6832642555236816
epoch 1, Step 475, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.833200693130493
epoch 1, Step 480, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.833592176437378
epoch 1, Step 485, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.8220341205596924
epoch 1, Step 490, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.7457640171051025
epoch 1, Step 495, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.825411081314087
epoch 1, Step 500, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.826152801513672
Val tp=18.0000, tn=9965.0000, fp=18.0000, fn=9999.0000
Val Acc=0.4992, pr=0.5000, re=0.0018, F1=0.6674, AUC=0.5383
epoch 1, Step 505, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.7964608669281006
epoch 1, Step 510, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.8510189056396484
epoch 1, Step 515, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.9176857471466064
epoch 1, Step 520, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.8510851860046387
epoch 1, Step 525, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.7261691093444824
epoch 1, Step 530, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.8053929805755615
epoch 1, Step 535, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.9349279403686523
epoch 1, Step 540, Training Accuracy=0.58594, UsedTime: 2.8601479530334473
epoch 1, Step 545, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.813232421875
epoch 1, Step 550, Training Accuracy=0.59375, UsedTime: 2.841656446456909
Val tp=5146.0000, tn=5674.0000, fp=4309.0000, fn=4871.0000
Val Acc=0.5410, pr=0.5443, re=0.5137, F1=0.6679, AUC=0.5560
epoch 1, Step 555, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.9094512462615967
epoch 1, Step 560, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.9421088695526123
epoch 1, Step 565, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.8581619262695312
epoch 1, Step 570, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.999098300933838
epoch 1, Step 575, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.8109405040740967
epoch 1, Step 580, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.8850042819976807
epoch 1, Step 585, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.8413331508636475
epoch 1, Step 590, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.721163749694824
epoch 1, Step 595, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.7854387760162354
epoch 1, Step 600, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 2.9258737564086914
Val tp=9501.0000, tn=811.0000, fp=9172.0000, fn=516.0000
Val Acc=0.5156, pr=0.5088, re=0.9485, F1=0.6677, AUC=0.5649
saving cost time: 33.539520502090454
epoch 1, Step 605, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.765889883041382
epoch 1, Step 610, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.9002127647399902
epoch 1, Step 615, Training Accuracy=0.46094, UsedTime: 2.9254982471466064
epoch 1, Step 620, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.9331798553466797
epoch 1, Step 625, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.7348546981811523
epoch 1, Step 630, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 3.016134262084961
epoch 1, Step 635, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.875119924545288
epoch 1, Step 640, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.8853843212127686
epoch 1, Step 645, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.9377899169921875
epoch 1, Step 650, Training Accuracy=0.54688, UsedTime: 2.995021343231201
Val tp=7739.0000, tn=2916.0000, fp=7067.0000, fn=2278.0000
Val Acc=0.5328, pr=0.5227, re=0.7726, F1=0.6681, AUC=0.5543
epoch 1, Step 655, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 3.008816957473755
epoch 1, Step 660, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.9302451610565186
epoch 1, Step 665, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.7788004875183105
epoch 1, Step 670, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.9206254482269287
epoch 1, Step 675, Training Accuracy=0.57812, UsedTime: 2.8770391941070557
epoch 1, Step 680, Training Accuracy=0.58594, UsedTime: 2.9892899990081787
epoch 1, Step 685, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 3.0226426124572754
epoch 1, Step 690, Training Accuracy=0.61719, UsedTime: 2.9504425525665283
epoch 1, Step 695, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 2.9117822647094727
epoch 1, Step 700, Training Accuracy=0.61719, UsedTime: 2.913363456726074
Val tp=4811.0000, tn=6217.0000, fp=3766.0000, fn=5206.0000
Val Acc=0.5514, pr=0.5609, re=0.4803, F1=0.6695, AUC=0.5786
epoch 1, Step 705, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 2.970163106918335
epoch 1, Step 710, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.9458398818969727
epoch 1, Step 715, Training Accuracy=0.54688, UsedTime: 2.9314231872558594
epoch 1, Step 720, Training Accuracy=0.47656, UsedTime: 2.6464312076568604
epoch 1, Step 725, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 2.9879024028778076
epoch 1, Step 730, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.8841769695281982
epoch 1, Step 735, Training Accuracy=0.66406, UsedTime: 2.9083614349365234
epoch 1, Step 740, Training Accuracy=0.60156, UsedTime: 2.90388822555542
epoch 1, Step 745, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.890779495239258
epoch 1, Step 750, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.9696552753448486
Val tp=5652.0000, tn=5141.0000, fp=4842.0000, fn=4365.0000
Val Acc=0.5397, pr=0.5386, re=0.5642, F1=0.6680, AUC=0.5565
epoch 1, Step 755, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 2.9684646129608154
epoch 1, Step 760, Training Accuracy=0.61719, UsedTime: 2.8662726879119873
epoch 1, Step 765, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.91127347946167
epoch 1, Step 770, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.9314675331115723
epoch 1, Step 775, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 2.937943696975708
epoch 1, Step 780, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.923021078109741
epoch 1, Step 785, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.7199249267578125
epoch 1, Step 790, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.9254274368286133
epoch 1, Step 795, Training Accuracy=0.60938, UsedTime: 2.7980270385742188
epoch 1, Step 800, Training Accuracy=0.58594, UsedTime: 2.9540090560913086
Val tp=4153.0000, tn=6758.0000, fp=3225.0000, fn=5864.0000
Val Acc=0.5455, pr=0.5629, re=0.4146, F1=0.6680, AUC=0.5692
saving cost time: 35.92570734024048
epoch 1, Step 805, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.9385342597961426
epoch 1, Step 810, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.969959259033203
epoch 1, Step 815, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.8976216316223145
epoch 1, Step 820, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 3.011605978012085
epoch 1, Step 825, Training Accuracy=0.63281, UsedTime: 2.9728243350982666
epoch 1, Step 830, Training Accuracy=0.57812, UsedTime: 2.921863079071045
epoch 1, Step 835, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 3.07442569732666
epoch 1, Step 840, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.9615626335144043
epoch 1, Step 845, Training Accuracy=0.43750, UsedTime: 2.9114034175872803
epoch 1, Step 850, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 3.006333589553833
Val tp=3957.0000, tn=6815.0000, fp=3168.0000, fn=6060.0000
Val Acc=0.5386, pr=0.5554, re=0.3950, F1=0.6684, AUC=0.5503
epoch 1, Step 855, Training Accuracy=0.57812, UsedTime: 3.037841558456421
epoch 1, Step 860, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.936110258102417
epoch 1, Step 865, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 2.9975790977478027
epoch 1, Step 870, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 2.949256420135498
epoch 1, Step 875, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.9777274131774902
epoch 1, Step 880, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.964160203933716
epoch 1, Step 885, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.9782471656799316
epoch 1, Step 890, Training Accuracy=0.45312, UsedTime: 2.9495339393615723
epoch 1, Step 895, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.996504545211792
epoch 1, Step 900, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.86970853805542
Val tp=9902.0000, tn=292.0000, fp=9691.0000, fn=115.0000
Val Acc=0.5097, pr=0.5054, re=0.9885, F1=0.6688, AUC=0.5207
epoch 1, Step 905, Training Accuracy=0.57031, UsedTime: 2.9251232147216797
epoch 1, Step 910, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.8436670303344727
epoch 1, Step 915, Training Accuracy=0.48438, UsedTime: 2.9677774906158447
epoch 1, Step 920, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.9285027980804443
epoch 1, Step 925, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 3.0459039211273193
epoch 1, Step 930, Training Accuracy=0.49219, UsedTime: 2.9689383506774902
epoch 1, Step 935, Training Accuracy=0.58594, UsedTime: 2.918386220932007
epoch 1, Step 940, Training Accuracy=0.53125, UsedTime: 2.980456829071045
epoch 1, Step 945, Training Accuracy=0.46875, UsedTime: 2.889941453933716
epoch 1, Step 950, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 2.8377809524536133
Val tp=1645.0000, tn=8882.0000, fp=1101.0000, fn=8372.0000
Val Acc=0.5264, pr=0.5991, re=0.1642, F1=0.6693, AUC=0.5722
epoch 1, Step 955, Training Accuracy=0.51562, UsedTime: 2.8657138347625732
epoch 1, Step 960, Training Accuracy=0.50000, UsedTime: 3.0531749725341797
epoch 1, Step 965, Training Accuracy=0.50781, UsedTime: 2.9553887844085693
epoch 1, Step 970, Training Accuracy=0.55469, UsedTime: 2.9313886165618896
epoch 1, Step 975, Training Accuracy=0.57812, UsedTime: 3.042778491973877
epoch 1, Step 980, Training Accuracy=0.56250, UsedTime: 2.904634714126587
epoch 1, Step 985, Training Accuracy=0.68750, UsedTime: 2.9549145698547363
epoch 1, Step 990, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 2.9157490730285645
epoch 1, Step 995, Training Accuracy=0.53906, UsedTime: 3.2426483631134033
epoch 1, Step 1000, Training Accuracy=0.52344, UsedTime: 3.016127824783325
Val tp=7620.0000, tn=3218.0000, fp=6765.0000, fn=2397.0000
Val Acc=0.5419, pr=0.5297, re=0.7607, F1=0.6696, AUC=0.5740
saving cost time: 37.10996174812317
...
epoch 1, Step 2805, Training Accuracy=0.67969, UsedTime: 3.360011100769043
epoch 1, Step 2810, Training Accuracy=0.62500, UsedTime: 3.470691204071045
epoch 1, Step 2815, Training Accuracy=0.68750, UsedTime: 3.3999030590057373
epoch 1, Step 2820, Training Accuracy=0.75781, UsedTime: 3.3989059925079346
epoch 1, Step 2825, Training Accuracy=0.73438, UsedTime: 3.405888319015503
epoch 1, Step 2830, Training Accuracy=0.74219, UsedTime: 3.4298250675201416
epoch 1, Step 2835, Training Accuracy=0.70312, UsedTime: 3.3849430084228516
epoch 1, Step 2840, Training Accuracy=0.71875, UsedTime: 3.4757003784179688
epoch 1, Step 2845, Training Accuracy=0.65625, UsedTime: 3.4178895950317383
epoch 1, Step 2850, Training Accuracy=0.61719, UsedTime: 3.369983673095703
Val tp=6970.0000, tn=6939.0000, fp=3044.0000, fn=3047.0000
Val Acc=0.6955, pr=0.6960, re=0.6958, F1=0.7085, AUC=0.7635
epoch 1, Step 2855, Training Accuracy=0.67969, UsedTime: 3.476698637008667
epoch 1, Step 2860, Training Accuracy=0.73438, UsedTime: 3.3620047569274902
epoch 1, Step 2865, Training Accuracy=0.75000, UsedTime: 3.380953073501587
epoch 1, Step 2870, Training Accuracy=0.71875, UsedTime: 3.3440542221069336
epoch 1, Step 2875, Training Accuracy=0.63281, UsedTime: 3.2682554721832275
epoch 1, Step 2880, Training Accuracy=0.71094, UsedTime: 3.2897355556488037
epoch 1, Step 2885, Training Accuracy=0.76562, UsedTime: 3.4428210258483887
epoch 1, Step 2890, Training Accuracy=0.74219, UsedTime: 3.430820941925049
epoch 1, Step 2895, Training Accuracy=0.72656, UsedTime: 3.3709802627563477
epoch 1, Step 2900, Training Accuracy=0.68750, UsedTime: 3.4617600440979004
Val tp=6151.0000, tn=7774.0000, fp=2209.0000, fn=3866.0000
Val Acc=0.6963, pr=0.7358, re=0.6141, F1=0.7115, AUC=0.7668
epoch 1, Step 2905, Training Accuracy=0.67188, UsedTime: 3.3540263175964355
epoch 1, Step 2910, Training Accuracy=0.67188, UsedTime: 3.384972095489502
epoch 1, Step 2915, Training Accuracy=0.60156, UsedTime: 3.367987871170044
epoch 1, Step 2920, Training Accuracy=0.72656, UsedTime: 3.387934923171997
epoch 1, Step 2925, Training Accuracy=0.58594, UsedTime: 3.262244939804077
epoch 1, Step 2930, Training Accuracy=0.67969, UsedTime: 3.3131632804870605
epoch 1, Step 2935, Training Accuracy=0.69531, UsedTime: 3.3430824279785156
epoch 1, Step 2940, Training Accuracy=0.75000, UsedTime: 3.38793683052063
epoch 1, Step 2945, Training Accuracy=0.73438, UsedTime: 3.515594005584717
epoch 1, Step 2950, Training Accuracy=0.71094, UsedTime: 3.395942211151123
Val tp=7139.0000, tn=7021.0000, fp=2962.0000, fn=2878.0000
Val Acc=0.7080, pr=0.7068, re=0.7127, F1=0.7217, AUC=0.7836
epoch 1, Step 2955, Training Accuracy=0.76562, UsedTime: 3.3839244842529297
epoch 1, Step 2960, Training Accuracy=0.69531, UsedTime: 3.565460443496704
epoch 1, Step 2965, Training Accuracy=0.74219, UsedTime: 3.6013646125793457
epoch 1, Step 2970, Training Accuracy=0.70312, UsedTime: 3.5993716716766357
epoch 1, Step 2975, Training Accuracy=0.77344, UsedTime: 3.38693904876709
epoch 1, Step 2980, Training Accuracy=0.77344, UsedTime: 3.4258296489715576
epoch 1, Step 2985, Training Accuracy=0.78125, UsedTime: 3.4198503494262695
epoch 1, Step 2990, Training Accuracy=0.76562, UsedTime: 3.5026280879974365
epoch 1, Step 2995, Training Accuracy=0.67969, UsedTime: 3.448772668838501
epoch 1, Step 3000, Training Accuracy=0.68750, UsedTime: 3.415830135345459
Val tp=5687.0000, tn=8148.0000, fp=1835.0000, fn=4330.0000
Val Acc=0.6917, pr=0.7560, re=0.5677, F1=0.7175, AUC=0.7685
saving cost time: 46.406840324401855
```

**I expect to know why does the training time and saving time increase every time when the model is saved, and what's wrong with the code?**

**how to change the code to save the iterator state or model, and not make time increase?**

I'd like to add to say, **Once I use Ctrl+C to break the program, and then I continue training from the checkpoint, the training time of each step becomes small as the beginning.**

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion there's not much you can do:

Tensorflow saves the models using [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/), it's encoding the values using [variable length serialization](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints).

When you start training your net weights are mostly set to zero (at least for the biases) So at first it's fast because it takes less time to encode zeros than more complex values.

I would say that for a given net the training time & saving time tends should tend to some value, but expecting to hit the limit with only 3k steps doesn't make sense, try to train with a 100k iterations to see if you reach a certain maximum time per step after a while.

Comment: one thing I forget to say. Once I use Ctrl+C to break the program, and then I continue training from the checkpoint, the training time of each step becomes small as beginning. Is this still normal？